# Joomla - 500 - Layout "default" not found

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

In my joomla 1.5 site, I am getting an error saying "**500 - Layout "default" not found**". I am new to joomla and have no idea why this error is coming. After reading some similar questions on joomla forum, I could find that my **tpl** folder (\components\com_content\views\frontpage\tmpl) doesnt have default.php files. is that  the reason for this error ? If yes, how can I fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

The file had to be there.
Please try to download the 1.5.26 patch package and upload all files to your root directory: [Joomla 1.5.0 to 1.5.26 Patch Package](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=6311)

This will fix the problem but I would suggest you to check security issues in your site and update it to a newer joomla version as soon as possible.

Comment: I have uploaded missing files. But now I am getting a different error
**500 - Unable to load renderer class**

Comment: Seem that your site is infected. Please try to switch your template with one of the joomla default to see if the problem is getting fixed.